# data type issue with dbnull c#

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I currently have the following property in my class that causes a problem when saving the value into the ms sql database.  If the value is "" the value recorded in the database is 0.  My problem is if the value is "" I need the database value to be null.  I've tried the following although obviously the data type is wrong and doesnt compile. The data type in sql is (float, null).  Any ideas?
Many thanks,

```
public double? MyProperty
{
    get { return obj.Test; }
    set { obj.Test = value; }
}
```

**My attempt**

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Test))
{
   obj.MyProperty = DbNull.Value;
}
```

Comment: if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Test))
{
   obj.MyProperty = null;
}

Comment: The value can't be `""`, because it's a `double?`, not a `string`. So it is either `null` or any `double` value. Also, you say you want to save the value to the database, but in the code you've shown, you try to set that property, but you don't show the code you use to actually save the value.

Answer (score -1):

Try this in sql

```
CASE @Date
 WHEN '' THEN NULL
 ELSE @Date
```

Comment: Not my downvote, but you only partially answered. `obj.MyProperty = DbNull.Value` whay about this?

Comment: @Date is date type varible in DB not varchar and as you wish which kind of datatype you want to be set

Comment: this is actually a good idea but unfortunately the repository is using the entity framework so I'm not sure how to access the query being executed.  I've sql profiled it and I can see the value which was null being sent to sql as 0 but I dont know how to update the EF SaveChanges() to handle the value differently..(?)  Any suggestions?